# Golfing Class of a language

Tags: discussion, code-golf, statistics

I feel like we may have enough data on this site to meaningfully break programming languages into classes.

What I mean by classes is akin to [Go's ranking system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_ranks_and_ratings):

> If a player can win 90% of even games against a 2 kyu player, the AGA believes he or she is 1.33 ranks higher, the EGF believes (s)he is 2.42 ranks higher, and the IGS believes (s)he is more than 3 ranks higher.

We may need to break the competition down into tags (e.g., a [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) puzzle may have a different ranking system than a [grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) puzzle (cough, Bubblegum).

The use case for this would be to more reasonably compare your success - If a Python answer beats one in J, the author should be pretty proud.  If Pyth beats Java by just a bit, the Java author should also be pretty happy with themselves (or the Pyth author ashamed).

Would anyone be interested in this endeavor?

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I think most of us have already formed subjective opinions; for example, I consider Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. in a higher and fairly well-defined "class" than Java, Rust, etc. Nevertheless, if you do attempt something like this, I'd be very curious to see the results! (I have a language-detection script floating around somewhere, in a Github Gist I think, that could come in handy.)

Comment: I think there are two (broad) schools of thought on what "success" means here in golf terms. One is getting the overall shortest by choosing the appropriate language for each task (choosing your tools). The other is finding the shortest given a certain tool (language). While I like to beat up on C# with Java as much as the next guy, it's not a true comparison across all golfs, because the real difference is (mainly) which builtins are there and how they're named. So I'm not sure I see how ranking each would help people in either school of thought judge their success.

Comment: To echo what Geobits said -- defining the tasks that make up the metric is going to be extremely difficult and subject to much debate. Many languages are very close on the Hello World challenge, simply because `"Hello, World!"` (with or without the trailing `"`) is a valid program in dozens of languages. Or ones where a particular language has a clear built-in that leapfrogs it ahead of where it would "normally" sit. Challenges like that would skew the numbers incorrectly. Not that I'm against the idea, it just needs a lot of rigor.

Comment: @TimmyD Yes - and I have no statistical background, so I'd like to get someone with more stats knowledge on board before pursuing it.

Comment: I honestly have no clue why this has been consistently downvoted so far. While the commenters have a point that it's going to be hard to figure out how to get the most meaningful data, I'm pretty sure that across *all* our code golfs we can find significant trends easily enough. It may be hard to determine with any certainty whether C# or Java is better for golfing, but I'm sure we can detect *some* fuzzy ranking. +1, I like the idea of trying to mine some data from our content.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, it's probably suspicion about motives. I'm fighting the temptation to downvote by reminding myself that we should [assume good faith](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55822/164922), but the context of previous meta questions by people who were pushing handicap systems does inevitably affect the subtext I read into this one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's a good point, but I'd rather downvote the post making use of such a handicap system than an attempt to gather some interesting data from our challenges.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I am not very active in meta and haven't read that thread.  I don't have motives aside from what is presented.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Also, for the record, I think a handicap system is a terrible idea.

Comment: Another reason is that it would be nice to see a language competition - some sort of aggregate of all the work folks have done to abuse languages.  Where does Perl beat Ruby?  Does D beat C?  Where does TI-BASIC beat Mathematica?

Comment: I downvoted because, not only would this be very difficult and many people would disagree with the classes due to the subjectivity involved, but defining language classes opens the door to attempts to impose handicaps, which I am strongly against.

Comment: We already have some data in response to [this code challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71117/20260).

Comment: I don't see why people are so opposed to this. Everyone knows that some languages are golfier are other. Most golfers already have a vague sense of the ordering, and surely actual statistics are better.

Comment: Seems like a fine idea to me. While it shouldn't be considered definitive, it'll probably be interesting.

Comment: @xnor Like I mentioned before, I don't think it's a worthwhile endeavor. The lines are too fuzzy to be able to create clear-cut classes, and there are lots of issues that skew the data such that the classes would not be meaningful (as I commented on Alex's answer).

Answer (score 36):

## Elo ratings, treating pairs of submissions as games.

I'm using the Elo system here.

Essentially, the solution is find the best solutions in each language to each challenge, and then treat each pair of such solutions as a match between those two languages, with the winner being the shorter submission.

Languages with less than 10 entries are discarded, and languages have a starting rating of 1000.

One drawback of this system is that ELO favors more recent entries. To compensate, I used a relatively low `K` value, which makes updates slower, and so old answer count for more.

The data is from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/459681), courtesy of Alex A. To run the code, put the two code blocks below in files with the names given, put the query csv file in ratings.csv, and run parse.py

### New results, with bug fix

In the old version of the code, there were two bugs:

- Answers with hyperlinks in the header were not counted.
- Languages with numbers in the name were not counted.

I have fixed both bugs. In doing so, the code now considers differently named versions of a language (e.g. Python 2.7 and Python 2) to be different languages. I don't think this is a major problem - allowing languages with numbers in the name is much more important.

Also, since many more answers are correctly parsed, more languages meet the threshold to be displayed.

#### March 2024 Results:

```
Thunno 2:                         2044
Vyxal:                            2015
Nekomata:                         1991
Jelly:                            1973
Husk:                             1967
Nibbles:                          1965
Vyxal 3:                          1918
SOGL V0.12:                       1905
Neim:                             1879
05AB1E:                           1871
Stax:                             1865
MathGolf:                         1827
Pyke:                             1820
MATL:                             1815
Canvas:                           1790
Japt v2.0a0:                      1769
Japt:                             1768
Brachylog:                        1755
Ohm:                              1705
Gaia:                             1701
Ohm v2:                           1695
Pyt:                              1693
Actually:                         1687
Pyth:                             1669
Convex:                           1633
Jolf:                             1616
Pushy:                            1545
Dyalog APL:                       1528
Burlesque:                        1528
APL:                              1525
Keg:                              1505
Pip:                              1501
CJam:                             1495
V:                                1493
BQN:                              1492
Charcoal:                         1479
cQuents:                          1470
TeaScript:                        1436
Uiua:                             1425
k:                                1407
Haskell + hgl:                    1386
x86 Machine Code:                 1382
x86 32:                           1381
J:                                1373
:                            1367
x86:                              1358
K4:                               1350
Attache:                          1324
stacked:                          1303
Braingolf:                        1303
Ly:                               1299
Add++:                            1280
Golfscript:                       1278
q/kdb+:                           1218
Aceto:                            1211
MY:                               1163
Q:                                1162
Vim:                              1156
TI:                               1147
Julia 1.0:                        1146
Raku:                             1145
Fourier:                          1123
Julia 0.6:                        1117
Octave:                           1107
Runic Enchantments:               1106
Factor:                           1104
APL+WIN:                          1101
Wolfram Language:                 1097
Proton:                           1082
Cubix:                            1073
Ruby:                             1067
PARI/GP:                          1057
Octave / Matlab:                  1057
bash+coreutils:                   1054
Matlab/Octave:                    1048
Regex:                            1043
QBIC:                             1042
Retina:                           1040
Curry:                            1039
DC:                               1030
Mathematica:                      1026
Julia:                            1019
Perl:                             1015
Bubblegum:                        1014
Retina 0.8.2:                     1011
MAWP:                             1005
R:                                1004
Cheddar:                          996
Labyrinth:                        985
Perl 5:                           963
Hexagony:                         951
Desmos:                           947
Arturo:                           940
Haskell:                          936
jq:                               934
Röda:                             934
befunge:                          926
JavaScript:                       915
CoffeeScript:                     912
Bash:                             912
Perl 6:                           904
Python 2:                         899
Zsh:                              895
GNU sed:                          890
Postscript:                       889
Alice:                            882
jq 1.5:                           878
Matlab:                           863
Groovy:                           852
CHIP:                             840
sed:                              824
Python 3.5:                       824
PowerShell Core:                  822
Python:                           813
AWK:                              807
PHP:                              797
Java:                             792
Knight:                           791
Python 3:                         790
Clojure:                          787
SmileBASIC:                       775
ES6:                              764
C:                                759
PowerShell:                       755
Python 3.6:                       749
QBasic:                           739
Elixir:                           729
Excel:                            725
Processing:                       722
PowerShell v2+:                   710
Python 3.8:                       705
Excel VBA:                        701
MMIX:                             692
Kotlin:                           684
Java 8:                           681
Scala 3:                          678
JavaScript ES6:                   672
Prolog:                           665
Google Sheets:                    664
Forth:                            646
Icon:                             639
Clean:                            637
REXX:                             635
Red:                              631
Yabasic:                          618
Batch:                            598
8th:                              583
VBA:                              580
Java 11:                          577
SpecBAS:                          574
T:                                571
Python 2.7:                       566
C#:                               565
Scala:                            561
Windows Batch:                    550
Rust:                             540
Dart:                             530
Swift:                            516
Common Lisp:                      513
tinylisp:                         494
Tcl:                              493
Fortran:                          491
Java 7:                           489
Lua:                              485
Brainfuck:                        470
Java 10:                          469
TSQL:                             467
Nim:                              467
F#:                               467
Swift 3:                          432
SWI:                              428
C++14:                            416
D:                                410
Racket:                           404
SNOBOL4:                          375
Oracle SQL 11.2:                  349
C++:                              349
Brain:                            343
Scratch:                          326
Go:                               318
Rockstar:                         295
Pascal:                           281
Whitespace:                       277
TS Type System:                   201
Deadfish~:                        169
Taxi:                             58
Shakespeare Programming Language: 15
```

*Editors note: The cutoff was set to `45` when generating the list, as it was the smallest cutoff (that was a multiple of 5) that didn't give any false positives like languages named `46 bytes`.*

*Editors second note: Because so many different names are used for "TS Type System", any lowercase language name matching the regex `typescript('s)?[^t]*types? *(system)?` is considered to be TS Type System.*

#### Code:

**elo.py:**

```python
STARTING = 1000
SCALE = 400
K = 10
PAD = 50

import itertools
def concat(x):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))

class Ratings:
    def __init__(self, challenges):
        langs = concat(challenges)
        self.ratings = {lang: STARTING for lang in langs}
        for challenge in challenges:
            self.update_challenge(challenge)

    def update_game(self, first, second, score):
        f_rat = self.ratings[first]
        s_rat = self.ratings[second]

        f_exp = 1/(1 + 10 ** ((s_rat - f_rat) / 400))
        s_exp = 1/(1 + 10 ** ((f_rat - s_rat) / 400))

        f_upd = K * (score - f_exp)
        s_upd = K * ((1 - score) - s_exp)

        self.ratings[first] += f_upd
        self.ratings[second] += s_upd

    def update_challenge(self, scores):
        for lang1 in sorted(scores):
            for lang2 in sorted(scores):
                if lang1 > lang2:
                    s1 = scores[lang1]
                    s2 = scores[lang2]
                    result = 1 if s1 < s2 else 0.5 if s1 == s2 else 0
                    self.update_game(lang1, lang2, result)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(key + ':' +
                ' ' * (max(len(lang) + 1 for lang in self.ratings) - len(key)) + str(val)
                         for key, val in sorted(((lang, int(self.ratings[lang]))
                             for lang in self.ratings),
                             key=lambda x:x[::-1], reverse=True))
```

**parse.py**:

```python
import csv
import re
import elo

CUTOFF = 100  # change as needed

lines = []
scores = {}
challenges = []
lang_counts = {}
canon_to_actual = {}

ALIASES = {"typescript('s)?[^t]*types? *(system)?": "TS Type System"}

ALIAS_KEYS = ALIASES.keys()

with open("merged.csv", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        lines.append((row["FirstLine"], row["ParentId"]))

count = 0
for line, challenge in lines:
    line = re.sub("<s(trike)?>.*</s(trike)?>", "", line)
    line = re.sub("<a[^>]*>", "", line)
    line = re.sub("</a>", "", line)
    match = re.match("<.*>(.*)</.*>", line)
    if match:
        line = match.group(1)
        lang = re.match("([^-,\(:]*)", line)
        if lang:
            lang = lang.group(1).strip()
            for alias in ALIAS_KEYS:
                if re.match(alias, lang.lower(), re.IGNORECASE):
                    lang = ALIASES[alias]
                    break
            canon = lang.lower().replace(" ", "")
            canon_to_actual[canon] = lang
            score = re.findall(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^0-9]+bytes?", line)
            if score:
                score = score[-1]
                score = eval(score.lstrip("0") or "0")
                c = scores.get(challenge, [])
                c.append((canon, score))
                scores[challenge] = c
                lang_counts[canon] = lang_counts.get(canon, 0) + 1

for c in sorted(scores, key=int):
    results = scores[c]
    c_map = {}
    for canon, score in results:
        if lang_counts[canon] >= CUTOFF and re.match("\w", canon):
            lang = canon_to_actual[canon]
            old_score = c_map.get(lang, score)
            c_map[lang] = min(score, old_score)
    challenges.append(c_map)

print(elo.Ratings(challenges))
```

---

Here are the original ratings, generated with the buggy code, for posterity.

#### 2016 Results

```
Jelly:                1906
Pyth:                 1711
GS:                   1674
Japt:                 1653
MATL:                 1607
Dyalog APL:           1580
J:                    1579
CJam:                 1578
Jolf:                 1559
Seriously:            1535
TeaScript:            1499
GolfScript:           1497
Pip:                  1478
Burlesque:            1460
APL:                  1443
O:                    1427
Vitsy:                1424
:                1384
Vim:                  1371
q:                    1355
K:                    1322
TI:                   1301
sh:                   1294
Octave:               1289
PARI/GP:              1272
dc:                   1269
GNU sed:              1229
Retina:               1213
x:                    1209
Bash + coreutils:     1207
Bash + GNU utilities: 1201
bc:                   1189
golflua:              1187
Sed:                  1182
HTML:                 1168
Julia:                1165
QBasic:               1156
Sage:                 1146
Ruby:                 1124
AWK:                  1101
ZSH:                  1086
Mathematica:          1083
Gema:                 1079
Bash:                 1079
jq:                   1060
Haskell:              1051
MATLAB:               1042
PowerShell v:         1028
Perl:                 1028
BBC BASIC:            1022
Piet:                 1019
Score:                1018
Shell script:         1017
Mumps:                1015
Languages:            1013
ECMAScript:           1012
Regex:                1000
LiveScript:           993
Tcl:                  989
CoffeeScript:         988
Groovy:               986
Postscript:           984
Windows PowerShell:   981
Powershell:           966
R:                    964
Befunge:              964
gawk:                 951
AutoHotkey:           934
Javascript ES:        931
Smalltalk:            928
STATA:                926
Matlab/Octave:        926
REBOL:                923
SAS:                  917
Clojure:              913
ES:                   909
PHP:                  908
Dart:                 908
Python:               894
JavaScript:           894
Node.js:              893
F#:                   880
Marbelous:            875
Excel VBA:            858
AutoIt:               853
Shell:                850
Common Lisp:          845
Brainfuck:            843
Lua:                  835
Processing:           832
Scheme:               824
CSS:                  823
Pure bash:            821
SWI:                  786
Game Maker Language:  785
FORTH:                778
SpecBAS:              776
Scala:                772
Cobra:                769
HTML + JavaScript:    758
Whitespace:           750
Applescript:          739
T:                    724
Batch:                720
Fortran:              715
Prolog:               711
Turing Machine Code:  708
C:                    706
SQL:                  704
VBA:                  703
Factor:               700
Kotlin:               690
JS:                   686
Pascal:               685
Erlang:               674
Emacs Lisp:           673
OCaml:                668
Racket:               658
VBScript:             654
VB.NET:               643
Swift:                636
D:                    621
Windows Batch:        612
Ceylon:               591
C++:                  587
Java:                 559
Oracle SQL:           548
Delphi:               539
Go:                   537
C#:                   535
Rust:                 528
```

Comment: This seems to get around the problem of some languages only being used on easy challenges, since two languages are only compared on challenges they have in common.

Comment: I also like that a language is scored by its shortest answer to a question, so it approximates the best a language can do rather than the average performance across a number of different users.

Comment: The Elo system might actually be better that you say, assuming you parse the answers in posted-order.  Languages here evolve over time.

Comment: @NathanMerrill They're sorted by question age, so you might be right.

Comment: I think one of the reasons jelly ranks so high is that dennis is the only one who knows how to use it. =)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: I don't think so. I think Dennis uses Jelly because it's short (as do I), rather than Jelly being short because Dennis uses it. (You can observe that Dennis tends to do equally well, relative to other entries in the same language, when using a language other than Jelly; but the entry ends up overall longer.)

Comment: Wish ShortC could be on the list. But almost no one uses it! (besides me and I didn't even make it). Though it's really a short*ener* because it just expands into C.

Comment: @Wezl Even after I fixed the first 2 bugs, shortC still isn't showing up. The language only appears 7 times in the results of my query, which is strange because it shows up way more than that when I search the site. Those 7 times are too few to give it a solid rating. I don't know what's wrong with the query, I didn't write it.

Comment: @isaacg 1 I was just saying I wish people would use it; right now there's no one to compete with.

Comment: It seems like the query only lists 50000 results, and those are neither the first 50000 nor the last 50000, but several chunks from random places (or am I not using it correctly?)

Comment: @isaacg Bug: TI-BASIC shows up as `TI`. (It seems that flags in answers are usually enclosed with code blocks (`<code>...</code>`) nowadays, so this should be easy to fix.)

Comment: [New SEDE query to get more reliable results (follow instructions to get full data)](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1473052/code-golf-scraper)

Comment: How does this deal with flags?  The Python parser is pretty difficult to read so I can't figure out exactly.

Comment: FYI for running this script next time, it will score Nibbles poorly because scores are listed like this: x bytes (y nibbles), and y is the last number so it will use that. I did some head to head comparison of nibbles versus jelly and it was 44 W, 9 D, 23 L, so 63% win rate, I would expect Nibbles to be rated higher than Jelly!

Comment: @TheThonnu - You've edited in "I have fixed ... Languages with flags in the header were not counted."  This is not 'fixing' a 'bug' - this is introducing a bug to correct code.  CGCC consensus is that *flags change the language*.  Heavy dependence on the use of flags to perform critical steps that are not counted in the byte score should *not* be ignored.  Ignoring flags will result that languages that often use flags to do this will now be falsely promoted (instead of the single-use flag-containing variants being listed separately).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen sorry, I forgot about that: I've rolled it back to the previous revision.

Comment: @Lyxal - Would you mind updating the query link and the code blocks?  The ones in the answer don't seem to work as-is, and even after tweaking seem to give somewhat different results...

Comment: Finally! The proof that `sed` outperformes `awk`. Otherwise, I have no idea what to do with that. (-;

Answer (score 21):

### K-means clustering by code length

**Note:** This is just a first-pass attempt with a very simple method. There are certainly better ways to approach this but at least this is a start.

My approach here was to get all answers to code golf challenges without bonuses that had (at least somewhat) appropriately formatted post headers, parse out the language name and byte count from the header, perform k-means clustering on the sizes with 6 groups, and for each language select the cluster into which most of the sizes for that language fell. Languages which have been used fewer than 10 times on the site, as well as any answer with a byte count greater than 170, were excluded.

The clusters are listed in ascending order of the values of their cluster centers.

Group 1, mean 12.03099

```
APL            GS2             Rebmu
Arcyou         Hexagony        rs
AutoIt         J               Sed
Batch          Japt            Self
BC             Jelly           Seriously
Beeswax        Jolf            Stuck
Befunge        K               TeaScript
Brachylog      Labyrinth       TI-BASIC
Brainfuck      Marbelous       Vim
Burlesque      MATL            Vitsy
Candy          Microscript     zsh
Clip           Minkolang
DC             Mouse
DUP            O
Element        Piet
ESMin          Pip
Factor         Platypar
Fission        Prelude
Gema           Pyth
GolfScript     QBASIC
```

Group 2, mean 31.75217

```
><>
CJam
Dart
F#
GTB
JQ
Julia
KDB
Mathematica
Matlab
Milky Way
PARI/GP
Perl
Q
Rebol
Regex
Scheme
Shell
Snails
```

Group 3, mean 54.14769

```
Awk
Bash
Clojure
D
Foo
Forth
Game Maker Language
Hassium
Pascal
PowerShell
R
Retina
Ruby
Sclipting
Smalltalk
Stata
```

Group 4, mean 79.65123

```
BBC Basic        Scala
CoffeeScript     SQL
Common Lisp      Swift
CSS              TCL
Emacs Lisp       VB.NET
Fortran          VBScript
GolfLua
Groovy
Haskell
JavaScript
Lua
Mumps
PHP
Processing
Prolog
Python
Racket
Rust
Sage
SAS
```

Group 5, mean 109.9524

```
C
C++
Ceylon
Delphi
Erlang
Gawk
Java
Postscript
VBA
```

Group 6, mean 147.5168

```
AppleScript
C#
Cobra
Go
HTML
OCaml
SpecBAS
Whitespace
```

### Thoughts on this grouping

This is roughly what one might expect, with the golfing languages in tier 1 and Java in tier 5. This particular grouping appears to be somewhat of a success in that regard. However, 6 was probably too many groups; 4 or 5 would likely be sufficient. Heirarchical clustering may be another interesting route for analysis since no number of classes is prespecified.

### Disclaimer

This should **not**, *under any circumstances*, be used to impose any kind of language handicap or restriction. It's merely for the sake of interest and giving folks a group to mentally compare their scores to, should they feel the need.

---

### For the curious

The data were collected via [this Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/459681). The analysis was done in R and is available via [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ararslan/f9418ba838a788ea0341).

Comment: I can spot one fatal flaw in this approach: challenges that would require significantly long code in golfing languages are usually not answered with those languages. For example, as the source of almost all of the Seriously answers, I admit that I usually don't try to answer a challenge with Seriously unless it's under 40 or so bytes (because any longer becomes unmanageable thanks to my poor design decisions). This skews Seriously towards a higher tier than what it probably should be.

Comment: @Mego Yep. There's a whole lot I didn't take into account. This is just a means of getting the ball rolling on an approach in the simplest possible way.

Comment: 404 on the gist. When you say "*perform k-means clustering on the sizes with 6 groups*", what exactly was the input to the clustering algorithm?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Looks like I accidentally deleted the gist. I've readded it and updated the URL. The input was the code lengths as parsed from the headers. Those were grouped into 6 classes using k-means and merged back to their respective languages. Then, for each language, I selected the class into which it fell most often.

Comment: As an avid vim user and a vim golfer, I'm really happy to see it in the same tier as the golfing languages. =D

Comment: I was quite surprised to see QBASIC in the top tier, until I looked at the QBASIC answers on the site. It's pretty good backup for Mego's comment. I suppose there's probably a somewhat better way to do this, but I'm not really sure it won't be filled with these outliers as well.

Comment: Perhaps sampling from a set of challenges with many answers in many different languages would be better, rather than across the entire site, to avoid the problem I brought up. Granted, I still don't think this will result in anything useful.

Comment: I think that @Mego's comment deserves some thought.  Perhaps we should score based on relation to the median answer of each question?

Comment: What poor souls answered in Delphi?

Comment: I think BATCH is in the first group because not many people answer in BATCH, and, when they do, it's usually on an easy question.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ more reasons why this is biased -- cool,  but biased

Comment: @Mego this is probably how Brainfuck ended up in group 1

Comment: where's vyxal? isn't it a programming lang that's used?