# Should Nominations for Language of the Month be community wiki?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, language-of-the-month, community-wiki

Should the [Nominations for Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-2021-edition) post be converted to a community wiki? What are the pros and cons of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

Community Wiki posts are specifically for posts that are edited often by multiple members of the community. The LOTM nominations body is a perfect example for this, and so the question *should* be made CW.

#### That said...

Unfortunately, making a question into a Community Wiki also makes all answers to that question Community Wiki as well, which appears to be the [biggest objection to this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59525651#59525651). This is an unfortunate side effect of the Community Wiki tool, and an ideal resolution of this would to be to *only* CW the question, and leave the answers as is.

This, unfortunately, isn't an option, and, in my opinion, the downsides of making a nomination CW are negligible. Mostly, the nominations posts are about the languages, not about any single person, and we should be encouraging people to edit in resources/pros/cons/information about the nominations if they believe them to be lacking. The only real drawback I can see is that using first-person language may get confusing, but this can be mitigated in a number of ways - if it's even an issue in the first place.

Overall, yes, I believe making the thread CW is a good idea.